# Why doesn't my kitten hunt like others?

Tags: cats, eating, junior-pets, hunting

My kitten doesn't hunt at all. It just keeps lying lazily in the carton box and when it feels hungry, it meows and we feed her. *Even when insects or rats go in front of it, she just looks at them and doesn't even try to catch them.*

**Is this behavior normal?**

**How do I teach her to hunt?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long ago, I had a kitten with similar behavior. I had gotten it particularly to catch mice. It just had no interest in chasing things.  I even put the kitten in a large area with a live mouse and the kitten just ignored the mouse.

I gave the kitten to some friends who wanted a cat for a pet, and I adopted an adult cat who was a proven mouse catcher.

A few months later the kitten grew into a cat, and the family who had it now, said she grew up to be a great mouse catcher.

To answer your questions:

> Is this behavior normal?

It is not abnormal.

> How do I teach her to hunt?

Keep playing with her, and encouraging her to chase toys.  Rewarding chase behavior with treats will likely help.

Comment: @MueezSiraj It's possible that this particular interest just hasn't "kicked in" yet, since she's only a kitten.

Answer (score 2):

I taught my kitten how to hunt by balling up a piece of paper and fluttering it around in her face in an obnoxious manner until she'd bite and pounce at it in annoyance. After a while it turned into play and shed come running the moment she heard a paper crinkle. I started tossing it around and she would very aggressively chase and attack it. Eventually she became highly interested in pursuing anything small and twitchy/fluttery and I haven't had an issue with rodents since. (excepting the time she decided to teach ME how to hunt and released a live squirrel in the bathroom while I was showering.)