# How to teach my cat to give death bite to rodents?

Tags: cats, behavior, play, rodents, hunting

There are some rodents in my house recently. As usual my cat, Bhutu, is excited about it.

But she prefers to play with the rodents. When the rodent freezes with fear she sniffs the rodent and then pushes it with her paws. Then as the rodent starts running again she starts chasing it again. She continues doing this until the rodent escapes. She never gives the death bite.

Why is she not giving the death bite and how to teach her to give the death bite?

Comment: Related [Why doesn't my kitten hunt like others?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19702/why-doesnt-my-kitten-hunt-like-others)

Comment: @JamesJenkins My case is different, my cat actively chase prey, but just likes to torment the prey and play with it. She just never kills the prey as if her fun time would then be over. She loves everything that moves, including prey. If prey freezes from fear she gets bored and pushes the prey with paws to encourage it to run. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While cats usually enjoy chasing rodents, my understanding is that cats aren't particularly fond of eating them. Most cats would rather play with them than eat them, and I don't think there's any practical way for you to teach them to kill. And not that you suggested it, but it would be cruel to deny her food to try to get her to kill them. I think that would be like forcing someone to survive on nothing but lima beans or brussels sprouts. ;^)

If she ever does kill a rodent, you can give her lots of praise, and maybe she'll be motivated to keep doing it. But then you're likely to be presented with rodent corpses when you least expect it... like when you're sleeping. Be careful what you wish for.